# PyQGIS save as .TAB not working?

Tags: pyqgis, tab

I am trying to save all the layers in Layers panel as MapInfo TAB file Then closed them all. But, Save as part doesn't work. There is no error but it doesn't save it. When I change the format to another format like "ESRI Shapefile" the code works well.

```
def packTables():

    from qgis.core import *
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    import os.path
    gda94CRS=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:38356")
    for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        layerName=layer.name()
        layerCRS=layer.crs()
        layerSource=layer.source()
        destination="D:/1"  + "/"+layerName
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, destination ,'System', gda94CRS,"Mapinfo TAB")
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)

packTables()
```

Comment: use `print QgsVectorFileWriter.errorMessage()` after the `writeAsVectorFormat..`. It may have some hidden errors there

Comment: Also, try changing your path to `"C:/Users/1/Desktop/duct.tab"`. Unescaped backslashes can give you troubles

Comment: I tried them all but it is not working. The fact is I tested following code and it works with any other format rather than "Mapinfo TAB"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this code to work the following line should change

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, destination ,'System', gda94CRS,"Mapinfo TAB")
```

it should change to

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, destination ,'System', gda94CRS,"Mapinfo File")
```

Comment: could you please explain why? the official ogr driver name is "MITAB", why is this not working but "Mapinfo File" is?